# A question concerning the history of Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell

So I am writing my thesis around the Maxwell equations, in one part I saw to speak about their history. The issue is, I found conflicting pieces of information as to who enunciated the laws first.

Let's take Faraday's law for example:
$$\oint \vec E \cdot d\vec s = - \frac{d}{dt} \int\vec B \cdot \vec n dA$$
I have searched in countless places about its first enunciation by Michael Faraday, but I found -through this site itself- that he formulated it verbally. The question I have here is: where do I find the citation/citations mentioning this by Faraday? And possibly who formulated this law in mathematical form with its reference for documentation.

The same question I may ask from you my friends about Gauss's law which is the second equation of the 4 equations.

Also, where can I find when and by whom exactly the local forms have been derived (with reference if possible)?

And overall, where can I find a well documented historical report concerning those 4 fundamental equations?

Thanks a lot and I apologize for taking some of your time.

Comment: A must read on this topic is [Whittaker's History of the theories of aether and electricity](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheorie00whitrich/mode/2up), freely available on Internet Archive. For your query specifically see chapters VI-VIII.